# Directory .ssh problem

Tags: ssh

I have been trying to Create a Directory .ssh in /home/user/.ssh and I keep getting error file directory already exist. I have not created .ssh directory. I have been using mkdir /home/user/.ssh  How can I get this to work?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You run `mkdir /home/user/.ssh` and you're told that the directory already exists. That's because it already exists. So you don't need to create it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory `/home/user/.ssh` is created automatically when ssh is installed. That is why you get a message saying the folder already exists. To check if the folder is present press `Ctrl+h` which will show all the hidden files in a file explorer.

All the best in you `ssh` exploration!

Comment: If the solution suggested works for you, please accept the answer, so others who have similar problem would know the working answer. All the best in using ssh!